# How to add drawer in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

Hello I have a simple app and i want to add a drawer to him I use react-navigation 4x and use `react-navigation-drawer` to implement Drawer in my app
I used it before sperate drawer in a single package and it's worked fine 
but when I use the new package I got this error

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.

although I export my screen

here is Code

```js
**navigator.js**

    import React from 'react';
    import {TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons';
    import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
    import {
      createDrawerNavigator,
      NavigationDrawerStructure,
    } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
    import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
    import ForgetPassword from '../screens/ForgetPassword';
    import Home from '../screens/Home';
    import Splash from '../screens/Splash';

    const AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      Authloading: {
        screen: Splash,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
        },
      },
    });

    const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
      HomeScreen: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: 'Home',
          headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
          headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
              style={{margin: 10}}>
              <Icon name="ios-notifications" size={28} color="#1DA1F2" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        }),
      },
    });

    const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
      HomeDrawer: {
        screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          drawerLabel: 'Home',
          drawerIcon: () => <Icon name="ios-home" size={28} color="#0496FF" />,
        },
      },
    });

    const Navigations = createSwitchNavigator({
      // Authloading: Splash,
      Auth: AuthStackNavigator, // the Auth stack
      App: DrawerNavigator, // the App stack,
    });

    const Navigator = createAppContainer(Navigations);

    export default Navigator;


**Home.js**

    //import liraries
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

    // create a component
    class Home extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Home</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }


    //make this component available to the app
    export default Home;


**App.js**

    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import Navigator from './src/navigations/navigator';
    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return <Navigator />;
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

### Edit

i just think NavigationDrawerStructure it's exports from react-native-drawer so that's my bad :)

so here is the component name as `NavigationDrawerStructure`

```
//Navigation Drawer Structure for all screen
class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
  //Structure for the navigatin Drawer
  toggleDrawer = () => {
    //Props to open/close the drawer
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer}>
          <Icon
            name="ios-menu"
            size={40}
            style={{margin: 10}}
            color="#1DA1F2"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

OR just add a button for a toggle in heder left inside Home stack like this

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon
            name="ios-menu"
            size={40}
            style={{margin: 10}}
            color="#1DA1F2"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
})
```

Comment: What is the path for `Route.js?`

Comment: `./src/navigations/Route.js` just a note other stack is work like createStackNavigator in AuthStackNavigator

Comment: shouldn't this `import Navigator from './src/navigations/navigator'` be `import Navigator from './src/navigations/Route` ?

Comment: @Max Yeah, it's my typo bad, but the issue still :(

Comment: try enclosing your package with {} in import statement eg ```import {NewModule} from ../the/path/to/file```

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami which path? Home screen?

Comment: yes, ```export default class HomeScreen extends Component``` with ```import HomeScreen from ../homeScreen``` / ```import HomeScreen from ../homeScreen```. Alternating these has worked for me in the past for the same error.

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami  Hmm, I use export default so I can't use import home screen with {} because,  I get The component for route 'Home' must be a React component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Import** is invalid. it don't have these objects in`react-navigation-drawer`

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import NavigationDrawerStructure from 'your file path'
```

**instead**

```
import {
      createDrawerNavigator,
      NavigationDrawerStructure,
    } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
```